# When tkinter.PhotoImage works with png files, why use pillow?

Tags: image, tkinter

I have seen many tkinter tutorials on images and almost all of them say that you have to use pillow to read png images, but tkinter.PhotoImage also does the job. Has there been a recent update to tkinter.PhotoUpdate or is there another reason for using pillow?

Answer (score 0):

> Has there been a recent update to tkinter.PhotoUpdate or is there another reason for using pillow?

Yes, there has been a fairly recent update to tkinter. PNG support is fairly recent, and still not available in every version of tkinter. You need a version of tkinter that is built on top of tk 8.6 or later.

You can check your version of tk by looking at the TkVersion attribute of the tkinter module:

```
import tkinter as tk
print(f"tk version: {tk.TkVersion}")
```